# ionic2 How to put an element outside of modal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to add an element outside of modal using Ionic2 like the image below.

The area surrounded by blue border is the element that I want to add.
The area surrounded by red border is the custom modal that I have created.

**Custom Modal.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar class="select-header">
        <ion-buttons left (click)="close()">
            <button ion-button>
                <img class="close" src="assets/images/close.png"/>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="region-selection">  
    <div class="select-all">
        <img class="selection not-selected" src="assets/images/region/check_none.png"/>
        <span>{{title}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="select-region">
        <ion-row class="regions-row" *ngFor="let row of rowsArray; let last = last" [ngClass]="{ last: last }">
            <ion-col *ngFor="let region of regions | slice:(row*3):(row+1)*3">
                <img class="selection not-selected" src="assets/images/region/check_none.png"/>
                <span [innerHtml]="region"></span>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing all your items inside the `ion-content` and remove the `ion-header` to have a structure like this

```html
<ion-content class="region-selection">

    <div class="outside-element">
        <!--element outside of modal-->
    </div>

    <!--This is your modal header wrapper-->
    <div class="modal-header">
        <ion-buttons left (click)="close()">
            <button ion-button>
                <img class="close" src="assets/images/close.png" />
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
    </div>

    <!--This is your modal header wrapper-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="select-all">
            <img class="selection not-selected" src="assets/images/region/check_none.png" />
            <span>{{title}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="select-region">
            <ion-row class="regions-row" *ngFor="let row of rowsArray; let last = last" [ngClass]="{ last: last }">
                <ion-col *ngFor="let region of regions | slice:(row*3):(row+1)*3">
                    <img class="selection not-selected" src="assets/images/region/check_none.png" />
                    <span [innerHtml]="region"></span>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Now you can use css to style and position the elements using the classes `.outside-element` , `.modal-header` , `.modal-content`

Also, make sure to set your `background-color` to `transparent`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried you solution as well. However, I was not able to do so because `backgound-color` to `transparent` would not behave as I expected. ( I have applied to class `region-selection`)

Comment: I have modified your suggestion and was able to achieve what I wanted. Thank you for inspiration.